# How to convert datetime format but keep the dates the same in the table in SQL?

Tags: sql, sql-server, date, datetime

Suppose I have the following table in `myTable`:

```
Name    |Date
------------------------------
A       | 12-23-2019 00:00:00
B       | 12-24-2019 00:00:00
C       | 12-25-2019 00:00:00
```

Where the datetime is formatted as `MM-DD-yyyy HH:mm:ss`.

I know I can use `CONVERT(varchar, GETDATE(), 20)` to convert the format using the current date. Is there a way to do this where I convert the date to `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` while keeping the values of the dates the same?

Comment: What is the datatype of the `Date` column?

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (When it comes do date/time many products are far from ANSI SQL compliant.)

Comment: The datatype for the `Date` column is `varchar`

Comment: You forfeit so much by storing dates as varchar.  You should consider changing your structure if possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your data is stored like this, then you should fix the data.  I would suggest:

```
update t 
    set date = convert(date, [date], 20);

alter table t alter column [date] date;
```

This will change the column to a *bona fide* date.  Then you don't have to worry about arcane formats.

Answer (score 0):

just update you table with your new format OR create a view